# Setup of IMTransform Video Processor for color space conversion

Tags: visual-studio, image-processing, sdk, ms-media-foundation, color-space

I am trying to do some basic color space conversion using Video Processor MFT. My camera natively supports NV12 and I need RGB24, to code some shader which will provide cartoon-like effect.

Here is definition of class Media which is used to perform MF.

```
class Media : public IMFSourceReaderCallback //this class inhertis from IMFSourceReaderCallback
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION criticalSection;
    long referenceCount;
    WCHAR                   *wSymbolicLink;
    UINT32                  cchSymbolicLink;
    IMFSourceReader* sourceReader;
    MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO *inputVideoTypes;
    MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO *outputVideoTypes;
    IMFMediaType* mediaType = NULL;
    IMFMediaType* streamType = NULL;
    IMFMediaType* streamType2 = NULL;
    IMFMediaType* streamType3 = NULL;
    IMFTransform **VP;

public:
    LONG stride;
    float bytesPerPixel;
    GUID videoFormat;
    UINT height;
    UINT width;
    WCHAR deviceNameString[2048];
    BYTE* rawData;
    UINT32 count;
    DWORD devices_found = 0;
    HRESULT CreateCaptureDevice();
    HRESULT SetSourceReader(IMFActivate *device);
    HRESULT IsMediaTypeSupported(IMFMediaType* type);
    HRESULT GetDefaultStride(IMFMediaType *pType, LONG *plStride);
    HRESULT Close();
    Media();
    ~Media();   

    // the class must implement the methods from IUnknown 
    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID iid, void** ppv);
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef();
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release();

    //  the class must implement the methods from IMFSourceReaderCallback 
    STDMETHODIMP OnReadSample(HRESULT status, DWORD streamIndex, DWORD streamFlags, LONGLONG timeStamp, IMFSample *sample);
    STDMETHODIMP OnEvent(DWORD, IMFMediaEvent *);
    STDMETHODIMP OnFlush(DWORD);

};
```

I am doing setup of IMFTransform in the following way:

```
inputVideoTypes = new MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO;
inputVideoTypes->guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Video;
inputVideoTypes->guidSubtype = MFVideoFormat_NV12;
outputVideoTypes = new MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO;
outputVideoTypes->guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Video;
outputVideoTypes->guidSubtype = MFVideoFormat_RGB24;
hr = sourceReader->GetNativeMediaType(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, i, &streamType2);
IMFActivate **transformActivateArray = NULL;
UINT32 MFTcount;
hr = MFTEnumEx(MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_PROCESSOR, MFT_ENUM_FLAG_ALL, inputVideoTypes, outputVideoTypes, &transformActivateArray, &MFTcount);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    exit(3);
}
if (MFTcount == 0)
exit(7);
VP = new IMFTransform*[MFTcount];
for (DWORD i = 0; i < MFTcount; i++)
{
    hr = transformActivateArray[i]->ActivateObject(__uuidof(IMFTransform), (void**)&VP[i]);
}
DWORD* inputCount = new DWORD[MFTcount];
DWORD* outputCount = new DWORD[MFTcount];
for (DWORD i = 0; i < MFTcount; i++)
{
    hr = VP[i]->GetStreamCount(&inputCount[i], &outputCount[i]);
}
DWORD **inputids = new DWORD*[MFTcount];
DWORD **outputids = new DWORD*[MFTcount];
for (DWORD i = 0; i < MFTcount; i++)
{
        inputids[i] = new DWORD[inputCount[i]];
        outputids[i] = new DWORD[outputCount[i]];
}
for (DWORD i = 0; i < MFTcount; i++)
{
    VP[i]->GetStreamIDs(inputCount[i], inputids[i], outputCount[i], outputids[i]);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    exit(5);
}
DWORD flag1 = -1;
DWORD flag2 = -1;
for (DWORD i = 0; i < MFTcount; i++)
{
    for (DWORD j = 0; j < inputCount[i]; j++)
    {
        hr = VP[i]->GetInputAvailableType(0, 0, &streamType);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            flag1 = i;
            flag2 = j;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (flag1 == -1 && flag2 == -1)
exit(2);
hr = VP[0]->SetInputType(0, streamType2, 0);
hr = VP[0]->GetOutputAvailableType(0, 0, &streamType3);
hr = VP[0]->SetOutputType(0, streamType3, 0);
```

The problem is that SetOutput method returns: cannot find a demanded attribute, and I dont really get, what is wrong.
Can anyone point where I am doing things bad way?
Thank you

EDIT: LogMediaType of input:

```
MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE    1280 x 720
MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX    2
MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE    MFMediaType_Video
MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING    3
MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING   1
MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE    {F72A76A0-EB0A-11D0-ACE4-0000C0CC16BA}
MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES    1
MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE   1
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE    30 x 1
MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO    1 x 1
MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT   1
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN  128849018881
MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES   2
MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE    2
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX  128849018881
{EA031A62-8BBB-43C5-B5C4-572D2D231C18}  1
MF_MT_SUBTYPE   MFVideoFormat_NV12
```

Logs of Output dosen't work

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
**pType** was nullptr.
```

EDIT2

I have only one VP enumerated by EnumEx method, and it has fixed number of input (1) and output (1) streams, so previous log is the only one log for input

**Edit 3**

```
hr = VP->SetInputType(0, streamType2, 0);
//MediaFoundationSamples::LogMediaType(streamType2);
DWORD dwIndex = 4;
hr = VP->GetOutputAvailableType(0, dwIndex, &streamType3);
hr = MFSetAttributeSize(streamType3, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 1280, 720);
hr = streamType3->SetUINT32(MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES, 1);
hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(streamType3, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1);
hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(streamType3, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
streamType3->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, 1);
streamType3->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, 2);
MediaFoundationSamples::LogMediaType(streamType3);
hr = VP->SetOutputType(0, streamType3, 0);
hr = VP->GetInputStreamInfo(0, &InputInfo);
hr = VP->GetOutputStreamInfo(0, &OutputInfo);
```

and processing in onReadSample method looks like:

```
hr = VP->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, NULL);
hr = VP->ProcessInput(0, sample, 0);
DWORD statusFlags;
hr = VP->GetOutputStatus(&statusFlags);
while (statusFlags == 0)
{
    hr = VP->ProcessInput(0, sample, 0);
    hr = VP->GetOutputStatus(&statusFlags);
}
DWORD outputStatus = 0;
IMFSample* outputSample;
MFCreateSample(&outputSample);
MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER outputBuffer = {};
outputBuffer.pSample = outputSample;
hr = VP->ProcessOutput(0, OutputInfo.cbSize, &outputBuffer, &outputStatus);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Mediafoundation samples, you have LogMediaType function [LogMediaType](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/master/multimedia/mediafoundation/common/logmediatype.h)

Can you show log for streamType2/streamType3.

Also check existing video media type from here [video-format-attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/medfound/media-type-attributes#video-format-attributes)

It could help you to find the missing attribute.

**EDIT1**

Beacause i use Windows Seven, i don't have the Video Processor MFT. I use Color Converter DSP, who can also do the color space conversion [Color Converter DSP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/colorconverter)

```
IMFTransform* pVideoColorConverter = NULL;
IMFMediaType* pVideoOutputType = NULL;
// RGB24 media type at index 10, but can be different on your system
DWORD dwRGB24Index = 10;

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CColorConvertDMO, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMFTransform, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pVideoColorConverter);
hr = pVideoColorConverter->SetInputType(0, pVideoInputType, 0);
hr = pVideoColorConverter->GetOutputAvailableType(0, dwRGB24Index, &pVideoOutputType);
hr = pVideoColorConverter->SetOutputType(0, pVideoOutputType, 0);

LogMediaType(pVideoInputType);
LogMediaType(pVideoOutputType);
```

Here is the log :

```
pVideoInputType (my camera provide YUY2 not NV12) :

MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE                MFMediaType_Video
MF_MT_SUBTYPE                   MFVideoFormat_YUY2
MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE                640 x 480
MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE            1280
MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT   1
MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES        1
MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE               614400
MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE               147456000
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE                30 x 1
MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO        1 x 1
MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE            2
MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE            {05589F80-C356-11CE-BF01-00AA0055595A}
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX      128849018881
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN      42949672961333333


pVideoOutputType :

MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE                MFMediaType_Video
MF_MT_SUBTYPE                   MFVideoFormat_RGB24
MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE                640 x 480
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE                10000000 x 333333
MF_MT_GEOMETRIC_APERTURE        <<byte array>>
MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO        1 x 1
MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE            2
MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE            1920
MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT   1
MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES        1
MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE               921600
```

**EDIT2**

Ok, your video input type seems to be correct.

Can you now log all input type (streamType) from all VP :

```
DWORD* inputCount = new DWORD[MFTcount];
DWORD* outputCount = new DWORD[MFTcount];

for(DWORD i = 0; i < MFTcount; i++){

    hr = VP[i]->GetStreamCount(&inputCount[i], &outputCount[i]);

    if(FAILED(hr)){
        exit(3);
    }
}

DWORD** inputids = new DWORD*[MFTcount];
DWORD** outputids = new DWORD*[MFTcount];

for(DWORD i = 0; i < MFTcount; i++){

    inputids[i] = new DWORD[inputCount[i]];
    outputids[i] = new DWORD[outputCount[i]];
}

for(DWORD i = 0; i < MFTcount; i++){

    hr = VP[i]->GetStreamIDs(inputCount[i], inputids[i], outputCount[i], outputids[i]);

    // By convention, if an MFT has exactly one fixed input stream and one fixed output stream, it should assign the identifier 0 to both streams
    if(hr == E_NOTIMPL && inputCount[i] == 1 && outputCount[i] == 1){

        inputids[i][0] = 0;
        outputids[i][0] = 0;
    }
    else if(FAILED(hr)){
        exit(4);
    }
}

for(DWORD i = 0; i < MFTcount; i++){

    // todo : log VP = i

    for(DWORD j = 0; j < inputCount[i]; j++){

        // todo : log stream id = inputids[i][j]

        DWORD dwTypeIndex = 0;
        hr = S_OK;

        while(hr == S_OK){

            // todo :log dwTypeIndex

            hr = VP[i]->GetInputAvailableType(inputids[i][j], dwTypeIndex, &streamType);

            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){

                LogMediaType(streamType);
                SAFE_RELEASE(streamType);
                dwTypeIndex++;
            }
            else{

                // todo : check hr, should be MF_E_NO_MORE_TYPES
                // if hr == E_NOTIMPL/MF_E_INVALIDSTREAMNUMBER... should be error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT3**

Here is a use of the Video Processor MFT : [VideoProcessor MTF sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/DX11VideoRenderer/cpp/Presenter.cpp)

It seems that you need to provide a D3DManager before using it (HRESULT DX11VideoRenderer::CPresenter::CreateXVP(void) -> line 1118)

I'm not sure for the D3DManager because i can't test it on my system.

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMFTransform, (void**)&m_pXVP);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    break;
}

hr = m_pXVP->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_SET_D3D_MANAGER, ULONG_PTR(m_pDXGIManager));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    break;
}

// Tell the XVP that we are the swapchain allocator
hr = m_pXVP->GetAttributes(&pAttributes);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    break;
}

hr = pAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_XVP_PLAYBACK_MODE, TRUE);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    break;
}
```

Check all m_pXVP and m_pXVPControl from the code.

**EDIT4**

According to your inputType, try to manually create the outputType, adding this attributes :

```
MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE                MFMediaType_Video
MF_MT_SUBTYPE                   MFVideoFormat_RGB24
MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE                1280 x 720
MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES        1
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE                30 x 1
MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO        1 x 1
MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT   1
MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE            2
```

So just after SetInputType, create the video media output type, and then call SetOutputType with this new mediaType.

You can first try only with MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE/MF_MT_SUBTYPE/MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, and then add others, one by one.

Comment: I added logs in the question's edits. Thank you for suggestions though

Comment: Okay I found out that it was issue with index of mediaType. Right index for RGB24 is 4 on my hardware. But then I get only a partial MediaType - Major_Type and Subtype of GUID only. How I can get/make whole list of attributes for VideoProcessor? Great thanks for your continuous help!

Comment: You welcome. Do you call SetInputType before GetOutputAvailableType and SetOutputType (like in your previous code) ?

Comment: I added an answer, see EDIT4

Comment: Thank you, it works. But now ProcessOutput doesn't want to cooperate with me. I get "Invalid Argument" as a HRESULT, and I dont't know what I am doing wrong. Code is above in EDIT

Comment: Just a remark,your loop is incorrect in while (statusFlags == 0)..., you don't have to use ProcessInput several times with the same sample... in each loop, you must provide the next input sample. The way it works : ProcessInput(sample1), ProcessInput(sample2), ProcessInput(sample3), etc...

Comment: Could you try : hr = VP->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &outputBuffer, &outputStatus); You have only one outputBuffer.

Comment: Unfortunately, still getting E_INVALIDARG

Comment: From GetOutputStreamInfo, can you log dwFlags (_MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO_FLAGS). Possible values are MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_WHOLE_SAMPLES             ,
  MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_SINGLE_SAMPLE_PER_BUFFER  ,
  MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FIXED_SAMPLE_SIZE         ,
  MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_DISCARDABLE               ,
  MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_OPTIONAL                  ,
  MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_PROVIDES_SAMPLES          ,
  MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES       ,
  MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_LAZY_READ                 ,
  MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_REMOVABLE

Comment: I don't really know how to log these flags, but I debugged it and dwFlags are 0. Both in InputStremInfo and OutputStreamInfo

Comment: try set input type before GetOutputStreamInfo

Comment: I set input type before output type and GetOutputStreamInfo. You can see this in EDIT3. Nevertheless dwFlags in OutputStreamInfo and InputStreamInfo are 0 :(

Comment: Perhaps you need to do this : hr = pAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_XVP_PLAYBACK_MODE, TRUE); // Tell the XVP that we are the swapchain allocator and perhaps you need to provide a D3DManager

Comment: MF_XVP_PLAYBACK_MODE - this modifier no longer exists, so I tried those ones, but without success:hr = VP->GetAttributes(&VPAttributes);
  hr = VPAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_TOPOLOGY_ENABLE_XVP_FOR_PLAYBACK, TRUE);
  hr = VPAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_XVP_SAMPLE_LOCK_TIMEOUT, FALSE);

Comment: Because i asked to your first question, you should set : the answer was usefull

Comment: Yes, sorry. I tried to give uparrow, but it said it will not count, so I thought that tick will count neither. But "answer was useful" already set :). Thank you for your time and effort to help me.